# How to extract stored functions and procedures from mysqldump file

Tags: awk, mariadb, gawk, ubuntu-server

So I upgraded to MariaDB 10.2 slightly haphazardly and lost my stored functions and procedures (no idea why). Luckily I do have weekly backups (mysqldump) but I don't want to rebuild the whole DB again.

There are some clever options out there - like upload the old DB backup into a new database on your cluster, then copy the functions across, but I thought easiest thing was to extract just the functions and procs from the mysqldump file. Here is my solution, hopefully you may find it useful, or improve upon it...

```
gawk '/Dumping routines for/,/Dump completed/{print}' backupfile.sql > foo1.sql
```

Then you can import back into the DB in the normal way...

```
mysql -u<user> -p<psw> DBNAME < foo1.sql
```

Comment: `gawk` is just an implementation of `awk`. If you tag your questions with `awk` in addition to `gawk` you'll get vastly more people reading them and get multiple answers almost immediately.

Comment: added - good point. (sorry force of habit always used gawk)

Comment: It's probably too late now for this question to get anyone looking at it, you might want to ask a new one and this time include concise, testable sample input and expected output.